# Publishing a workflow in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I try to publish an empty workflow for example, I get a message:

> System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: The time zone ID '' was not found on the local computer.
>      at System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(String id)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWebWorkflowSecurityContext.CreateOrUpdateServiceGroup(SPWeb lookupWeb, SPAppPrincipal app)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWebWorkflowSecurityContext.b__3()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
>      at Mic

Viewing the ULS log simply shows this error.
The workflow can be saved. SP1 is installed. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered, probably by Andrew Ferin here: [Can't publish workflow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/44b03d4f-95de-43e8-a470-ace9d558c328/cant-publish-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomization).

Quote from there:

> Thanks! I've already fix it.
>   MS doesn't provides TIMEZONE.XML as update. 
>   I took it from [site](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=FF921AD8B6623B17&id=FF921AD8B6623B17%2117694&authkey=%21ABhQa1YL75C-ZeY) and add a KeyName attribute for each timezone.

This solution works for me.

Comment: It's a quite fun to see my own answer on another resource.
Thank you, I forgot to post it here